# Read data from json link and download that to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a json link as below:

> url =
>   "https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-variations?index=gainers"

How to download these data to pandas dataframe.

Comment: I get 405 Method not allowed when fetching the URL

Comment: Sir I have now change the link as the previous one was having some error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I went about getting all data to DataFrame. I have added a new column called 'legend' that will allow you to see each data separately if needed:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

# needs header
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
                         'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
                         'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}


URI = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-variations?index=gainers'
# since data is returned as json, we can use .json func
data = requests.get(URI, headers=headers).json()


print(data['legends'])

# each legend carries data, so we will append all data and add col legend
dfs = pd.DataFrame([])
for legend, _ in data['legends']:

    df = pd.DataFrame(data[legend]['data'])
    df['legend'] = legend
    dfs = dfs.append(df, ignore_index=True)


print(dfs)
```